# Datatable modify column with row

Tags: c#, datatable, multiple-columns

I want to modify my table in a Datatable. I know that I have to use `linq` and group the results. 
Before:

```
ID     Name   LastName
1      Kiki    ha 
3      lola    mi 
2      ka      xe 
2      Kiki    ha
```

After:

```
Name  LastName   1   3   2
Kiki   ha        x       x
lola   mi            x
ka     xe                x
```

My original code:

```
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("table"); 
    table1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String)); 
    table1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String)); 
    table1.Columns.Add("Lastname", typeof(String)); 

    object[] a1 = { 1, "Kiki", "ha" }; 
    object[] a2 = { 3, "lola", "mi" }; 
    object[] a4 = { 2, "ka", "xe" }; 
    object[] a5 = { 2, "kiki", "ha" };
    table1.Rows.Add(a1); 
    table1.Rows.Add(a2); 
    table1.Rows.Add(a4);        
    table1.Rows.Add(a5);
```

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
    var result = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                 group t1 by new {ID = t1.Field<String>("ID")} into grp
                  select new
                     {
                         ID = grp.Key.ID,
                         //something must be there
                     };
     DataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Do you really want to add a column for every id in that table?

Comment: yes, I want to add columns for every ID, so it would be column 1, column 3 and column 2

Comment: ... and the `x` is a `x` or a bool?

Comment: Of course the x indicates that user has that ID.

Comment: I'd prefer x than bool :p coz then when i convert it to excel i can see x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
var nameGroups = from row in table1.AsEnumerable()
                 group row by new
                 {
                     Name = row.Field<string>("Name").ToLower(),
                     LastName = row.Field<string>("Lastname").ToLower(),
                 } into NameGroups
                 select NameGroups;

var tblOut = new DataTable();
tblOut.Columns.Add("Name");
tblOut.Columns.Add("LastName");
var distinctIDs = table1.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(r => r.Field<string>("ID"))
                        .Distinct();

foreach (var id in distinctIDs)
    tblOut.Columns.Add(id);

foreach (var grp in nameGroups)
{
    var row = tblOut.Rows.Add();
    row.SetField<string>("Name", grp.Key.Name);
    row.SetField<string>("LastName", grp.Key.LastName);
    foreach (DataColumn idCol in tblOut.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(2))
    {
        bool userHasID = grp.Any(r => r.Field<string>("ID") == idCol.ColumnName);
        row.SetField<string>(idCol, userHasID ? "x" : "");
    }
}
```

Note that i output the lowercase names because i needed to group by case insensitive.

**Edit**: Here's a screenshot of the `DataTable` in the debugger window:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code,i can see table but without column 2 and bool parameters, dataGridView1.DataSource = tblOut; What should i do?

Comment: @UniLe: I've edited my answer to show you that the DataTable is what you have asked for.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and it works for me. Maybe your grid is not large enough or you have to scroll. However, that is another question. You can see in the debugger that the result is correct. Just add a breakpoint and inspect the `tblOut` in a quick-watch-window. Then click on the reading-glass icon.

Comment: how can i change your code but instead of x whould be another values from the table column?